# Title Patterns was printed in exactly its self

Tags: 7

Look at image: 
[image: Title Error]
[image: view in brwoser]

If you look to image, you will find a [current-page:page-title] | [site:name] patterns was printed, not replaced to real site name & node title ...etc, I dont know what is wrong was happens...

Token module, Page-title module was enabled, also when i try to change
 PATTERN, its give me an error
 invalid tokens: [current-page:page-title], [site:name].  invalid tokens: [current-page:title]  invalid tokens: [site:name], [site:slogan]. (for front page)

Also, Im clear cach, and run a cron, and trancate table cashes from database manually ....

thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have token and page title modules enabled?

Comment: @Ayesh K yes mate, its was enabled ..

Comment: Hello and welcome. You reported a bug, and bugreports are not allowed here. Also, there is no actual question in your "question" at the moment. And even if you will make it a question, you should give more information: What modules related to tokens and page title was enabled? What tokens are said to be available for title field (screenshot would be nice)? And so on. We can't deal with bugreports and we can't reliably guess without data.

Comment: @Molot, thank you for info, I will do some changes now ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `[current-page:title]` instead of  `[current-page:page-title]`

- Run cron manually and clear the performance cache. If it doesn't help then
- Reload the same version of the Token module. If you use drush, command is:

  drush dl token-[version]

Comment: when I try to change PATTERN, its gie me an error 
 invalid tokens: [current-page:page-title], [site:name].
 invalid tokens: [current-page:title]
 invalid tokens: [site:name], [site:slogan]. (for front page)

Comment: Try my updated answer and tell if it helps

Comment: I will try it now, thank you very much .. (I will be back after finished it) ..thanks for help

Comment: Thank you mate, your answer help me really, 

When I check a problem, Im not found any token was available in list .. so Im update all module with token also, and its work .. thank you very much for help .. drush token will be resolved a problem ... (Y)